# Change value in array Angular 4

Tags: angular

**I have:**

```
button *ngFor="let button of buttons" (click)="changeValue()"
```

**I have:**

```
export class Home {

  howMany: number = 10;
  zoom: number = 5;

  buttons = [
    { howMany: 40, zoom: 10 }.
    { howMany: 100, zoom: 2 },
    { howMany: 23, zoom: 35 }
  ]

}
```

**I have:**

3 buttons on the screen.

**How to create:**

When I click button number 1:
**"howMany"** change from **10** to **40** and **"zoom"** from **5** to **10**

etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

**Template**

```
<button *ngFor="let button of buttons" (click)="changeValue(button)">
```

**TS**

```
export class Home {

  howMany: number = 10;
  zoom: number = 5;

  buttons = [
    { howMany: 40, zoom: 10 }.
    { howMany: 100, zoom: 2 },
    { howMany: 23, zoom: 35 }
  ]

  changeValue(button) {
    this.howMany = button.howMany;
    this.zoom = button.zoom;
  }

}
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you my friend!! :D